# JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: Error while trying to convert string to dictionary

Tags: python, nlp, data-science

I have a txt file like this:
text='{"id": "a364ebd4", "reason": "delay", "description": "I bought a tv. It's not working and the manager said it was "the best" "}'

When I try to convert the string into a dict using json.loads()
textf = json.loads(text)
textf

I get the error JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 3290 (char 3289).

I think the problem is the quotation marks at "the best" but I don't know how to remove them without disturbing the quotation marks at "id","reason", etc., which I need to process the information.

Comment: this is not a properly formed json string

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the final value in the dict (ie. the value of the "description" key, you will see that it contains a single `'` in the word `it's` which breaks the text string. And there are also double quotes `"` inside double quotes which create errors.

You should use this: instead

```
'{"id": "a364ebd4", "reason": "delay", "description": "I bought a tv. Its not working and the manager said it was the best"}'
```

So the working code looks like this:

```py
import json


text='{"id": "a364ebd4", "reason": "delay", "description": "I bought a tv. Its not working and the manager said it was the best"}'

j = json.loads(text)
print(j)
```

and the result is this:

```
{'id': 'a364ebd4',
 'reason': 'delay',
 'description': 'I bought a tv. Its not working and the manager said it was the best'}
```

Comment: But imagine that I have thousands of txt files  with error like that. I cant manually change them. what do you suggest?

Comment: well, if the text files do not contain readable json strings, you could run a process to correct the text errors (this is what the linter does). For example, a simple algo might remove all quotations...  best asked as a separate question tho !!